# How to filter pull requests on GitHub by commentaries authors?

Tags: github, pull-request

There are a plenty of Pull Requests on GitHub. Each pull request goes through code review process by one of a few developers. Is there a way to filter out only those pull requests, that has been reviewed by a specific user?

I've tried multiple filters:

- build-in GitHub `is:open mentions:nattfodd` - shows only PRs where there are replies to `nattfodd's` commentaries, skips PRs with nattfodd's commentaries, but w/o replies to them
- simply typed nickname to search field - same behavior

Is it even possible to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github is already providing a very powerful search API, which includes
***Search by a commenter within an issue or pull request***.

You can use the filter in the following way: `commenter:nattfodd`.

For more information please refer the official docs on how to [search by commenter](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-commenter).

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. You should include the relevant information directly in the post as well as a link to the source.

Comment: @Polygnome - I just did that.

Comment: Problem: The search bar does not search within the currently open PR, it searches through ALL PR's. How do I search in a given PR #12345 ?